# Has anything changed regarding the background location service in Xamarin.ios?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm using Xamarin Forms to develop a solution that needs a permanent background service, which also uses locations. I've  ticked background mode, fetch and always on, but the location updates become less frequent with time. After 20 mins of background processing, the location updates seem random, ranging from 5mins to 1h. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
public class LocationManager
    {
        protected CLLocationManager locMgr;
        public event EventHandler<LocationUpdatedEventArgs> LocationUpdated = delegate { };
        public LocationManager()
        {
            locMgr = new CLLocationManager();
            LocMgr.DesiredAccuracy = CLLocation.AccurracyBestForNavigation;
            locMgr.PausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false;

            locMgr.ActivityType = CLActivityType.AutomotiveNavigation;
            locMgr.DistanceFilter = CLLocationDistance.FilterNone ;

            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
            {
                this.locMgr.RequestAlwaysAuthorization();  
            }

            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(9, 0))
            {
                this.locMgr.AllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true;
            }

           LocMgr.StartUpdatingLocation();
        }

        public async void StartLocationUpdates()
        {

            if (CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled)             
            {
               if (LocMgr != null)
                {
                    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(6, 0))
                    {
                        LocMgr.LocationsUpdated += LocationsUpdated;  
                    }
                    else
                    {                        
                        LocMgr.UpdatedLocation += LocationsNewUpdated;
                    }
                   
                    LocMgr.StartUpdatingLocation();                    
                    
                    LocMgr.Failed += (object sender, NSErrorEventArgs e) => {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Error);
                    };
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Location services not enabled");
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**CLLocationManager** provides many options for filtering and configuring location data, including the frequency of updates. In this example, set the DesiredAccuracy to update whenever the location changes by a meter. For more information on configuring location update frequency and other preferences, refer to the CLLocationManager Class Reference in the Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager

```
if (CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled) {
    //set the desired accuracy, in meters
    LocMgr.DesiredAccuracy = 1;
    LocMgr.LocationsUpdated += (object sender, CLLocationsUpdatedEventArgs e) =>
    {
        // fire our custom Location Updated event
        LocationUpdated (this, new LocationUpdatedEventArgs (e.Locations [e.Locations.Length - 1]));
    };
    LocMgr.StartUpdatingLocation();
}
```

Sample link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/ios-samples/location/

Comment: I have a logfile that shows how many times it updates. After exactly 20 mins in the background, the updates don't come as frequent, ranging from 5mins to 1h. I've read the documentation and hope I understood it. Tried a few methods, including the use of CLLocationManagerDelegate and UIApplication.BeginBackgroundTask, and arrived back to my example, which seems to be the norm. So... what am I missing?

Comment: You can set some breakpoints to see if the method is excute when reached the DesiredAccuracy .

Comment: I've taken the location service and created a new app to test only this feature. I tried to do a bit of processing to figure out what to send to the database in the previous project which seems to annoy the OS and shuts down my app temporarely. I will continue to test and see if I can come up with a solution.